# Combine All USA Block Group Census Shapefiles together

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, census

As the title suggests, I'm trying to load in all the SHP files from the Census found here (https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/BG/), and merge them all together as 1 large shp file for the entire US overcoming issues with duplicate polygons.

I adopted code found from a question asked previously but could not get it to work as it stops once I hit state 6.

> Error in download.file(x, destfile = path, mode = "wb") :
> cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/BG/tl_2019_06_bg.zip'

> In addition: warning messages: 1: In download.file(x, destfile = path,
> mode = "wb") :   downloaded length 29680232 != reported length
> 50020624

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
library(RCurl) 
library(rgdal)

# get the directory listing
u <- 'ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/BG/'
f <- paste0(u, strsplit(getURL(u, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, ftplistonly = TRUE), 
                        '\\s+')[[1]])

# download and extract to tempdir/shps
invisible(sapply(f, function(x) {
  path <- file.path(tempdir(), basename(x))
  download.file(x, destfile=path, mode = 'wb')
  unzip(path, exdir=file.path(tempdir(), 'shps'))
}))

# read in all shps, and prepend shapefile name to IDs
shps <- lapply(sub('\\.zip', '', basename(f)), function(x) {
  shp <- readOGR(file.path(tempdir(), 'shps'), x)
  shp <- spChFIDs(shp, paste0(x, '_', sapply(slot(shp, "polygons"), slot, "ID")))
  shp
})

# rbind to a single object
shp <- do.call(rbind, as.list(shps))


# write out to wd/USA.shp
writeOGR(shp, '.', 'USA', 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: See if the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264250/merge-two-shapefiles-in-r) works for you.

Comment: That unfortunately did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @a_swoosh I saw in the gis stackexchange that you found a single file that had everything combined. Where was this file?

Comment: @FrancisA—Scroll to the bottom: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2021/shp/